# Need help passing file from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am allowing users to upload a file from the view which will eventually be passed to the model through controller actions. However, there is a particular situation that is giving me trouble.

I have the followong ViewModel that I'm passing to the view:

```
   public class RegisterStudentViewModel
        {
            public Login loginViewModel;
            public Person personViewModel;
            public PersonResume personResViewModel;
         }
```

When the form is submitted, I use some validation logic to make sure the fields entered were applicable, and if any of the validation fails, I send the ViewModel that I'm using back to the view, to make sure that the fields that had information entered correctly are stored. Before this though, I have also made sure that the file uploaded is binded to the model that it belongs to, like this:

```
 if (res != null)
                {
                    PersonResume resumeViewModel = createResume(res, personModel);
                    vm.personResViewModel = resumeViewModel;
                }

                SetUpView(vm, da);
                result = View(vm);
            }
```

so that when the validation fails but the resume wasn't one of the fields that failed and I want to display the uploaded resume, I can use the following code in my view:

```
 @if (Model.personResViewModel != null && Model.personViewModel.id == 0)
{
    <th class="editAddLabel">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.personResViewModel.ResumeFileName, "Resume File Name")

    </th>

    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("View your resume", "linkDownload", "Student", new { id = Model.personViewModel.id, resume = Model.personResViewModel}, null)

    </td>
}
```

to pass to the following controller method that will allow the link to be downloaded:

```
  public FileResult linkDownload(int id, PersonResumeViewModel resume)
    {
        DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
        PersonResume displayResume = new PersonResume();
        if (id != 0)
        {
            displayResume = da.getPersonResumeByID(id);
        }
        else
        {
            displayResume.ResumeData = resume;

        }

//some more code that downloads file
}
```

I know that in the view, the personResViewModel is not null, but when I look at the controller method, it is null and I can't do anything with it. Am I not passing my argument in correctly?

Comment: Why don't you just pass the id and get it from the database like you do in the "id != 0" case? What does the PersonResumeViewModel contain that you're trying to pass back in and does your rendered link actually contain that info?

Comment: because when the validation fails, none of the information was actually passed onto the database. This makes the personid == 0. The PersonResumeViewModel is me actually creating a PersonResume object using the file uploaded, and passing it to the viewmodel so that it can be accessed later since it is not in the actual database at this point @KeithRousseau

Comment: When ActionLink renders the link do you see the info from the PersonResumeViewModel in the url? I think it's reasonable to not allow them to download the resume until the form uploads successfully, but I also don't know your requirements.

Comment: well, when the validation fails, it returns the view but all the information they typed in is still in the form so that they don't have to start the form all over. It'd be weird if they entered an invalid email, for example, and the view returned all the information they entered previously EXCEPT for the resume. The only thing they should have to change in the new view is their email to a valid one, but now not only can they not download the resume they uploaded, but it prompts for them to actually upload a resume again @KeithRousseau

Comment: @KeithRousseau my co-worker said I could use Session for this, but I don't really know much about that. I guess I'll look into that

Comment: The problem with Session is scalability. If they're guaranteed to hit the same server then it's valid. If you really need to save it, you could just save it where you normally would and store a list of temp files in the db.

Comment: @KeithRousseau using session is completely messing up my logic for everything else. I dont understand why I cant just pass the personResume from the controller to the view, then back from teh view to the controllermethod to download it. I feel like my original code should work

Comment: You're trying to put the resume into an ActionLink though. That's not going to work. You can put it back in the form and have them resubmit it.